# How to change NavBar Image from different View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

Previously when I only needed 1 navbar image, I would just do

```
UIImage *navBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbarimage.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:navBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

in AppDelegate, and that would stay throughout the app.

However, now I need to change the navbar images when going from a rootview to a tableview. 
I tried putting

```
    UIImage *navBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"vybeNavBarEmpty.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:navBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

in the viewwillappear of my tableview class, but nothing changes.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: check whether that code is executing or not when you are going from rootview to a tableview

Comment: @Tendulkar the code is being executed

Comment: try to  use self.navigationcontroller.navigationbar instead of UINavigationBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vybeNavBarEmpty.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.png"]];
```